# jquery data table json data not binding ? mvc4

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried like this but something is wrong and i was unable to move forward .

**My View Code:**

```
<html>    
    <head>   
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"  type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/demo_page.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/demo_table.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                debugger;
                alert("dfdfd");
                $('#myDataTable').dataTable( {
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "sName": "ID",
                                        "bSearchable": false,
                                        "bSortable": false,
                                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                            return '<a href=\"Details/' +
                                            oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                                            alert(oObj);
                                        }
                                    },

                                    { "sName": "COMPANY_NAME" },
                                    { "sName": "ADDRESS" },
                                    { "sName": "TOWN" }
                    ]
                });
            });

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
                <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Company name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Town</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </table>
</body>
```

My home controller code :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

   public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
   {
       return Json(new
       {
           sEcho = param.sEcho,
           iTotalRecords = 97,
           iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
           aaData = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {"1", "Microsoft", "Redmond", "USA"},
                new string[] {"2", "Google", "Mountain View", "USA"},
                new string[] {"3", "Gowi", "Pancevo", "Serbia"}
                }
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Till `"aoColumns" : { "sName" : "ID"}` the code is working fine I created some alerts to know till where its going on .

**Data from Json is not at all binding** 
**JSON OUTPUT :**

```
{
   "sEcho":null,
   "iTotalRecords":97, 
   "iTotalDisplayRecords":3,
   "aaData":[
              ["1","Microsoft","Redmond","USA"],
              ["2","Google","Mountain View","USA"],                    
              ["3","Gowi","Pancevo","Serbia"]
            ]
}
```

**Update:**
MY error's : Also edited view part check above

```
'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
Unhandled exception at line 3398, column 4 in http://localhost:49205/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Unhandled exception at line 39, column 7 in http://localhost:49205/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js
0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined
Unhandled exception at line 2, column 1 in http://localhost:49205/Scripts/index.js
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

REGARDS

Comment: Not sure but is it `"aoColumns"` or `"aoColumnDefs"` ?

Comment: my code not even calling the code in controller : "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler".. . Any other way . if you know any better links i can look at those for some other way

Comment: DId you try removing coldefs? Try it once and check if the table loads the data. That way you can isolated the problem in column definitions.

Comment: The only problem I see is the sEcho is null. Try assigning some value to it. Check the [secho](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) parameter

Comment: yes tried but issue is starting at this point $('#myDataTable').dataTable( { . data is coming perfectly .
ERROR i am facing :
Unhandled exception at line 113, column 29 in http://localhost:49205/
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Try setting your script URL to `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Same goes for JQUERY js file as well.

Comment: updated my errors . edited as you said also you can check on view . Script file issue ? uff too confusing . any ideas mate

Comment: `'jQuery' is undefined` ... You need to include jQuery, your include obviously isn't working.

Comment: may be :( i will try and get back at you . Ty chris & nilesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution that i am not completely satisfied . I am using j-query 2.1 when i am using it i am getting J-query Undefined exception . **But  NOW i tried with j-query 1.4 it is working fine now :)**

Thank you for your views Ty

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: my problem is solved now . i hope this way around solved my issue . . I thought this will be helpful to someone and posted . I feel this is answer , Am i wrong ?